# Delete multiple selected items from the listbox, as well as from the list

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am creating a simple GUI program to manage priorities.

I am having troubles with deleting selected items from the listbox, as well as from the list at the same time.

For instance, in C#, I would create a following method:

```
void Remove()
{
    Priority priority = new Priority();
    try { priority = FindPriority(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text); }
    catch { return; }
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
            {
                priorities.RemoveAll(x => x.Subject == eachItem.Text);
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
                listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have not selected any priorities!", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

How can I do this in Python?

I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: Did you check the [listbox documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm)? Given you appear to have experience, I'd say maybe best consider using wxpython or pyqt to build an interface, they are a little more advanced but offer more and (i.m.o.) more intuitive options for building GUI's.

Comment: When you do `self.buttonAdd = Button(...).grid(...)`, you are assigning `None` to `self.buttonAdd` because `.grid(...)` returns None.

Comment: What should I do then? Just Button(...)?